Keep curve alignment when source geometry changed
For example when the edge changed by Merge by Distance node
the curve alignment may reversed, its can be solved by using Reverse Curve node
but how to make it automatically always aligned to the desired direction?




Why don't you use the node Resample Curve after the separation and conversion to a curve? https://i.sstatic.net/UDOvbrzE.png

sometimes i need the curve point count and position has exact same as the source edges.

Are you looking for a deterministic way to align the curve (e.g. clockwise looking from its center towards the world origin)? Because I do not imagine how a right (or a wrong...) alignement can be expected from the collection of "unsorted" edges produced by the Boolean Mesh node.

Hi @StefLAncien i think that not what i mean,
and my question is not related with the world origin its like based normal direction?,
and this question it's not for curve only it can be used in case need to keep the direction for extrude (edges) directly without curve.

You could just compare the dot product of the face normal and the normalized vector you get from subtracting the position of the face from the location of the "Subtract" object. Flip them if the faces are pointing toward the center of the subtract object? This is a bit jankier cause there's no guarantee the subtract object origin will be exactly in the center of the mesh like in this example but... could work?

Well, I honestly don't quite understand the task in this case, because if you merge the points in this way, you neither get a usable mesh, nor exactly the number of points that the original geometry contained. But Jakemoyo's answer might help.

the “original” i mean is not exactly from the original mesh,
i mean from the mesh after Merge by Distance sorry for the confusion,
Also I don’t understand math so I don't know how to set up like Jakemoyo's said
so i confused and can't test it :(
